# Why UNION used in a stored procedure in derived table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, union

I am not author of the stored procedure and I am wondering why they used `UNION` in `SELECT` statement when selecting from the derived table ...

If I comment out the whole `UNION ALL SELECT` statement, I get the same result with the same basically performance.

So I am just wonder why it is there? What kind of trick does it makes?
Below is the whole stored procedure in case I am missing something

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[rptActivityLog] --'1/1/2016', '2/3/2016'
   (@DateFrom datetime = null,
    @DateTo datetime = null,
    @UserGuid uniqueidentifier = null,
    @CurrentUserGuid uniqueidentifier = NULL)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

    DECLARE @UserID SMALLINT

    SELECT @UserID = UserID 
    FROM tblUsers 
    WHERE (UserGUID = @UserGuid)

    DECLARE @ValidOfficeGuids TABLE (OfficeGuid uniqueidentifier primary key)

    --if user is in tblUserQuotingOffice then use only that Office 
    --otherwise they will have access to all offices
    IF EXISTS (SELECT OfficeGuid 
               FROM tblUserQuotingOffice
               WHERE UserGuid = @CurrentUserGuid)  
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @ValidOfficeGuids
            SELECT OfficeGuid 
            FROM tblUserQuotingOffice
            WHERE UserGuid = @CurrentUserGuid
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @ValidOfficeGuids
            SELECT OfficeGUID 
            FROM tblClientOffices
    END

    DECLARE @compareDateFrom DATETIME 
    set @compareDateFrom = CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @DateFrom, 101) AS DATETIME)

    declare @compareDateTo datetime
    set @compareDateTo = DateAdd(ms, -2, DateAdd(d, 1, CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), DATEADD(day, 7, @DateTo), 101) AS DATETIME)))

    --First get the log entries
    declare @logResults table
    (
        ID int primary key not null
        , IdentifierGuid uniqueidentifier
    )

    insert into @logResults
    select 
            l.ID
            , l.IndentifierGuid
        from 
            tblLog l
        where
            l.ActionDate between @compareDateFrom and @compareDateTo
            and l.IndentifierGuid is not null

    select 
        distinct
            T.UserName
            , T.ControlNo
            , T.InsuredPolicyName
            , Replace(Replace(T.[Action],Char(10),''),Char(13),'') as [Action]
            , T.ActionDate
            , T.LineName as LOB
        from
    (
        select 
                u.UserName
                , q.ControlNo
                , q.InsuredPolicyName
                , l.[Action]
                , l.ActionDate
                , ll.LineName   
                , l.UserID 
            from    
                @logResults r
                inner join tblLog l on r.ID = l.ID      
                inner join tblUsers u on l.UserID = u.UserID
                inner join tblQuotes q on r.IdentifierGuid = q.QuoteGUID
                inner join lstLines ll on q.LineGUID = ll.LineGUID  
--      WHY DO WE USE BELOW UNION  STATEMENT??????????????????????????????????
        union
        select 
                u.UserName
                , q.ControlNo
                , q.InsuredPolicyName
                , l.[Action]
                , l.ActionDate
                , ll.LineName   
                , l.UserID
            from    
                @logResults r
                inner join tblLog l on r.ID = l.ID      
                inner join tblUsers u on l.UserID = u.UserID
                inner join tblQuotes q on r.IdentifierGuid = q.ControlGUID
                inner join lstLines ll on q.LineGUID = ll.LineGUID      
    ) T     
    WHERE IsNull(@UserID, T.UserID) =  T.UserID
    order by            
        T.ActionDate
```

Comment: Well, there is a difference in the join with tblQuotes, looks like the union is meant to union two different datasets (one for QuoteGUIDs and one for ControlGUIDs, whatever they might mean..)

Comment: Ah missed that...

Comment: OOH!!!!  you are right!! Dindnt notice that. Thanks

Comment: haha you are welcome!

Comment: Good eye! I looked expecting to find difference and still didn't see it.

Comment: @Rigerta you can post an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference in the join with `tblQuotes`, looks like the union is meant to union two different datasets (one for `QuoteGUIDs` and one for `ControlGUIDs`)